# Distinct operation in spark structured streaming with a window operation

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

I want to implement a distinct operation in Spark structured code.
I have already watermarked it and windowed it, but still, Spark is not able to execute it.
FYI - Distinct comes under the list of unsupported operations in Spark streaming, but I feel that distinct in a window is a very basic operation to not be supported by Spark. [Reference](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#unsupported-operations)

Snippet:

```scala
    val fieldLocationJobDF = eligibleJobDF
      .withWatermark("timestamp", "24 hours")
      .groupBy(window(col("timestamp"), "15 minutes"), col(JOB_ID), col(JOB_LOCATION_TYPE))
      .agg(col(JOB_ID), col(JOB_LOCATION_TYPE))
      .distinct()
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

_

Comment: shouldn't you have aggregate functions within `agg`? like `count` or `max`

Comment: What distinct value you need in the above example?